# using % is IN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-in

Usually when one has to search in oracle for a single where condition where you don't know the exact condition we use :

```
Select * from Table where column like '%Val%'
```

If I have to run check for multiple condition we use `IN`

```
Select * from Table where column in ('Value1','ABC2')
```

How we combine the two ?i.e , search for a bunch of values in DB when the exact value is not know
The below code doesn't give the desired result as it considers the whole as a string .

```
Select * from Table where column in ('%Val%','%AB%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * from Table where column like  '%Val%' or column like '%AB%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from Table where column like '%Val%' or column like '%AB%'.....
```

I know its little hard to write you can create a vertical list and change \n and \r by '% and %' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE instr(column, 'Val', 1) > 0 or instr(column, 'AB', 1) > 0
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE contains(column, 'Val', 1) > 0 or contains(column, 'AB', 1) > 0
```

Comment: CONTAINS is an Oracle Text operator, and will only work on columns with the appropriate index.